# UML types of depedency

Tags: oop, uml

What is the difference between << import >> and << access>> dependency in UML? Are they used only for package diagrams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<<access>>` dependency means that objects from the client package *can access* objects from supplier package. In the case of the `<<import>>` dependency the classes from the supplier package *are imported* to the client package and they can be accessed directly. These dependencies are used only in package diagrams or diagrams that depict packages.